# fancyhdr error when putting in graphics

Tags: fancyhdr

When I try to put \includegraphics in the header of a tex document using fancyhdr I get an error saying that \includegraphics is an undefined control sequence. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{marginnote,calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{%
  left=37.5mm,
  right=12.5mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  bindingoffset=0mm,
  headheight=30pt,
}

\newlength{\myoddoffset}
\setlength{\myoddoffset}{\marginparwidth + \marginparsep}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset[leh,roh]{\marginparsep}
\fancyheadoffset[loh,reh]{\myoddoffset}
\lhead{ \includegraphics[scale=1]{logo.png}  } 
\rhead{ Title2}

\begin{document}

dddd

\end{document}
```

Here is the error:

```
!Undefined control sequence.\f@nch@olh ->\includegraphics[scale=1]{logo.png}\strut\end{document}*
```

How do I fix this so that the logo shows up?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\usepackage{graphicx}` is missing in your preamble.

Comment: Oh. Stupid, I'm so used to it being there by default. Thank you